# Unity Microphone start recording with lag

Tags: unity-game-engine, microphone

I'm trying to record a sample from the microphone by this code

```
private bool recording = false;

void Start () {
    Button btnREC = recordButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    btnREC.onClick.AddListener(RecordToggle);

    Button btnPlay = playButton.GetComponent<Button>();
    btnPlay.onClick.AddListener(PlayAudioSource);
}

public void RecordToggle(){
    if (recording) {
        StopRecording ();
    } else {
        StartCoroutine("StartRecording");
    }
}

IEnumerator StartRecording(){
    source.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 10, 44100);
    while(!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)){
        yield return true;
    }
    recording = true;
    recIndicator.SetActive (true);
    StopCoroutine("StartRecording");
}
```

In the Unity editor, all is fine but in the build, I have a lag between button click and recording start (my recIndicator also shown after a lag). How can I fix this and start recording immediately after the button click?

Comment: Btw, you don't need to call `StopCoroutine`, just let the method exit and it'll be stopped automatically.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The delay occurs at line source.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 10, 44100);
If I don't use coroutine and do the same things in function my indicator shown immediately, but recording starts after the same lag in the build. In the editor, the record starts immediately.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this @user2857947? I have the same problem